# Как посмотреть логи фласка в pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pythonanywhere

Как посмотреть логи фласка в pythonanywhere?

Comment: Перейти на вкладку web, выбрать слева ваше приложение, прокрутить вниз до раздела "Log files".

Answer (score 2):

@insolor:

> Перейти на вкладку web, выбрать слева ваше приложение, прокрутить вниз до раздела "Log files"